# Why is my experimental inductive reactance not directly proportional to frequency

Tags: electric-current, voltage, frequency, inductance

For a lab report, I am measuring the voltage across a 300 mH coil when connected to an alternating current supply at different frequencies. From this, I want to graph the inductive reactance (calculated using V/I) of the coil against frequency.

However, graphing it reveals a linear correlation that intercepts significantly above the origin, and does not have the slope of 1.88 that it should have, according to
the formula for inductive reactance: X = 2πfL, where 2πL should be the slope of the graph (which equals 1.88).

Here is my data:

[image]

And here is the graph:
[image]

If I extend the range of frequencies, I get the following data:

[image]

Which has a much greater slope than anticipated, and also does not go through the origin.

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestions as to what could be causing this.

Comment: Does the coil have any pure resistance?

Comment: A roughly 100$\Omega$ DC resistance seems perfectly possible for an inductor. You could also verify this by just using the resistance setting of a multimeter, if you're allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

If the coil has a finite DC resistance it will present what looks like inductance at zero frequency. this will cause your line to miss the origin by an amount that equals the DC resistance of the coil.

I recommend that you use frequency increments that are spaced thusly: 500-1000-1500-2000-3000-4000-5000-6000-7000-8000-9000-10,000 and see what the linear fit and correlation coefficient are.

I also recommend taking 5 measurements at each frequency increment and plotting the result using error bars instead of points.

Answer (score 1):

Inductors have a DC resistance, as others have mentioned. But simply assuming that $\omega L = <V>/<I>$, where $<V >$ and $<I>$ are the RMS values read from a multimeter, ignores the phase factor introduced by the resistive ($R$) and reactive ($\omega L$) parts of the impedence. This phase factor introduces a trigonometric factor into your analysis.

Rather than provide a complete solution to your problem, I'll let you do the research on RL circuits.

Comment: My capacitor does seem to have a DC resistance of 130Ω. I tried to find out how the phase angle factors into it, but no sources properly explain... how would it affect the inductive reactance? Can I not graph rms voltage across my inductor / current, against frequency?